# How can I include JAVASCRIPT in my CSS on my visualforce page

Tags: javascript, css, visualforce

We have decided to track our website's analytics by the below HOTJAR snippet below. We are using Visualforce page which has CSS as Header. We would like to include this JAVASCRIPT into this CSS.

Our HOTJAR tracking Script:

```
  <script>
    (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
        h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
        h._hjSettings={hjid:748410,hjsv:6};
        a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
        r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
        a.appendChild(r);
    })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
</script> 
</head>
</html>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
        <script>
            $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            $j(document).ready(function(){
                $j('#portalheaderbot').hide();
            });
        </script>
```

The below code is our Header which is in CSS. We would like to include into this so that whenever someone clicks on a page, HOTJAR can track the traffic.

```
<apex:page cache="false" showHeader="false" contentType="text/css"  controller="BSHeaderCSSCntl">

   /*Uncomment this for development*/
    @import url("{!URLFOR($Resource.PD_FLP360, 'style/bootstrap.css')}");
    @import url("{!URLFOR($Resource.PD_FLP360, 'style/main.css')}");


/*Uncomment this before deploying to prod.*/
/*    @import url("{!URLFOR($Resource.PD_FLP360, 'style/bootstrap.min.css')}");
    @import url("{!URLFOR($Resource.PD_FLP360, 'style/main.min.css')}");*/

    @import url("{!URLFOR($Resource.PD_FLP360, 'style/font-awesome.min.css')}");
    /* Hide SFDC stock communities components */
    .bPageHeader {
        display: none;
    }
    #tabContainer {
        display: none;
    }
    #sidebarCell {
        display:none;
    }
    /* Override to fix display of Chatter forms. Specific targetting to override computed styles.*/
    .chatterPage, .profilePage, .zen-bodyInner {
        font-size: 14px; 
    }
    .chatterPage h3, .profilePage h3, .chatterPage legend, .profilePage legend, .pollquestion{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .userProfilePage .vfButtonBar a.editLink img {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .zen-navigation {
        height: 52px !important;
    }
    .uploadFile {
        height: 52px !important;
    }
    .bottomBar{
         height: 49px !important;
    }
    .zen-data table {
        -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
        -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
        border-bottom-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
        border-bottom-style: none;
        border-bottom-width: 0px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-image-outset: 0px;
        border-image-repeat: stretch;
        border-image-slice: 100%;
        border-image-source: none;
        border-image-width: 1;
        border-left-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
        border-left-style: none;
        border-left-width: 0px;
        border-right-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
        border-right-style: none;
        border-right-width: 0px;
        border-top-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
        display: table;
        font-family: arial, helvetica, clean, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        table-layout: fixed;
        text-align: left;
        zoom: 1;
    }
    .feedcontainer {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

    .threecolumn, .userProfilePage {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .threecolumn .mainContent .lowerMainContent {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .threecolumn .mainContent, .profilePage.userProfilePage .mainContent {
        width: initial;
    }
    .threecolumn .centerContent, .userProfilePage .centerContent {
        width: 72%;
    }
    .chatterPage .threecolumn .rightContent, .chatterPage .userProfilePage .rightContent { 
        display: none;
    }
    .userProfilePage .headerContent {
        width: auto !important;
    }

    /* Hide default stock page title */
    .bPageTitle {
        display:none;
    }
    /* Override default background on page blocks and related lists */
    .bPageBlock.brandSecondaryBrd.secondaryPalette, .bPageBlock.bEditBlock.brandSecondaryBrd {
        border: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    /* Override font size for stock pages */
    .outerNoSidebar, #bodyTable {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #bodyTable { /* Fix for DownlineMap rendering in FF */
        table-layout: fixed;
    }

    /* Custom code from Custom Settings */
    {!cssSettings.Custom_CSS__c}

    /* Additional custom code */


    /* Override heading display format */
    #fl-pagetitle {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    /* Override modal popup look and feel */
    .modal-title {
        color: rgb(218, 157, 39);
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }    
    .modal-content {
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
    /* Fix bottom padding */
    .panel {
        /*padding: 13px 13px 13px 13px;*/
    }

    /* Fix header display */
    #bootstrap-body {
        margin-top: 100px;              
    }


    #publishersharebutton {
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-clip: border-box;
        background-color: #C9920E;
        background-image: none;
        background-origin: padding-box;
        background-position: 0% 0%;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-size: auto;
        border-bottom-color: #ce9423;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-left-color: #ce9423;
        border-left-style: none;
        border-left-width: 0px;
        border-right-color: #ce9423;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-right-width: 1px;
        border-top-color: #ce9423;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-top-style: none;
        border-top-width: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 18.699979782104492px;
        list-style-image: none;
        list-style-position: outside;
        list-style-type: none;
        outline-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        outline-style: none;
        outline-width: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        padding-top: 6px;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    }

    .publishercontainer.defaultState #publishersharebutton:hover, .publishercontainer.defaultState #publishersharebutton:active, .publishercontainer.defaultState #publishersharebutton:focus, .publishercontainer.defaultState #publishersharebutton.onHover {
        background-color: #C9920E;
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#C9920E 0,#C9920E 100%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#C9920E 0,#C9920E 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#C9920E 0,#C9920E 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top,#C9920E 0,#C9920E 100%);
        border: 1px solid #ce9423;
    }

    #bootstrap-body ul li {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    #bootstrap-body .site-title { // Override site title for Chatter page
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        display: inline;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetca, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 49px;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: auto;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        line-height: 53.900001525878906px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 60px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-top: 40px;
        text-shadow: rgb(34, 34, 34) 2px 2px 5px;
        width: auto;
    }
    /* Hide dropdown box on right hand side of Chatter */
    #moderatorMutton{
        display: none;
    }
    /* Text wrapping for long names */
    #profile-name {
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    /* Hide contentWrapper as this interferes with min page width */
    #contentWrapper, .zen-page {
        display: none;
    }
    #site-header{
        padding-top: 35px;
    }

    /* Override size of list view so that it renders correctly on small screens */
    .listBody, .x-grid3, .x-grid-panel, .x-panel-body-noheader,  .x-grid3-scroller {
        min-height: 300px;
    }

    /* Widget header */
    .panel-heading span.wdgHeader {
        display: table;
    }
    #fchArea{
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 800px;
    }
    <!-- Hotjar Tracking Code for www.foreverliving.com -->

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include JS from CSS. The only thing you can do is to declare some kind of background image or alike, which creates a request to the tracker, like:

```
body:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(/path/to/tracker);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  display: block;
}
```

But be aware that css will be cached, so you probably need a url like:

```
/path/to/tracker?t=<timestamp>
```

Whereby the timestamp needs to be generated on each page request.

Comment: The smart thing to do would be to include the Javascript in the web page that uses the CSS file.

Comment: I know, but the question was how to include JS from CSS. Since that is not possible, one needs another way to contact the server. If JS can be included in the page, all the CSS stuff would not be needed altogether.

Comment: Yes, you're right, using an image would allow you to include the tracker in the CSS, however the tracker is written in Javascript which doesn't get executed, because it's an image, nor can it somehow create a full http-request that originates in the browser of the client and is loaded there so the Javascript will be executed. Can it?

Comment: No, no JS can be executed, but with the url of the image one can fine tune the request, by using query parameters. Additionally all other request headers can be processed on the server. But Yes, the final call to the tracker needs to be done on the server this way.

Comment: Thanks Philip and Kiko, I have very less knowledge in CSS and JS since I am a Salesforce guy. Could you please help me with the solution?

Comment: @viniethanirudh You simply cannot include JS from CSS. The solution above uses what is also called a »tracking pixel«. If that is not an option for you I might say that you cannot solve the problem. Can you insert HTML in the page?

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot include HTML in the page above How would you want us to explore on the tracking pixel concept?

Comment: The basic concept is: Make the browser try to download an image. That is done with the `background-image: url(…)` within the css. Let the url of the image point to some serverside script (php or alike). Process the request there, call the tracker and send out some image data with the correct header.

Comment: I have included the snippet in our Footer. It shows HotJar links in the Head when we inspect